# Is there a way to programmatically restart Activity keeping its ViewModel (as if it was a system config change)?

Tags: android, viewmodel, display, android-multi-display

We have an Android device that in addition to a built-in display supports external USB displays, so user can attach a USB touch screen.

When that happens we need to move app UI to that newly attached display.

According to the [docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/activity-launch) there is a way of doing it by starting the activity via an `Intent` and specifying target display ID:

```
startActivity(
    Intent(),
    ActivityOptions.makeBasic()
        .setLaunchDisplayId(displayId)
        .toBundle()
)
finish()
```

And it works indeed. But the downside, unlike a config change, the `ViewModel` is lost, which breaks user flow.

Is there a way (maybe to craft such an `Intent`) so that it restarted the `Activity`, but kept the `ViewModel`, similarly how system does it for a system config change?